# Updating zone.js past v.0.13.0 - Cannot redefine property transform

Tags: angular, jestjs, ts-jest, zone

While updating our project from Angular 13 to 15, we ran into an issue with all of our tests failing due to error:

```
FAIL  src/app/app.component.spec.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: Cannot redefine property: transform
        at Function.defineProperty (<anonymous>)

      16 | });
      17 |
    > 18 | Object.defineProperty(document.body.style, 'transform', {
         |        ^
      19 |   value: () => {
      20 |     return {
      21 |       enumerable: true,

      at Object.<anonymous> (setup-jest.ts:18:8)
```

I tracked down the issue to zone.js v0.13.1+. [This bug ticket](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/50756) points to the root of the problem. I'm seeing their workaround near the bottom, but I'd prefer to not use them if possible (and I can't say for sure if that workaround would work in my case as the error is pointing to the setup-jest file, not a spyOn in test file). Can anyone recommend how to solve this so that we'll be able to update above the 0.13.9 version and eventually 0.14 when we goto jest 29 & angular 16?